# Laravel use custom class

Tags: laravel-5

I created a new class under `/app/UserRepositories/UserRepository.php`.
Now i want to use it in my `AuthenticateUser.php` under `/app`.
I tried to import it like that `use App\Repositories\UserRepository;`
but I get still the same error: `Class does not exist`

**UserRepository.php**

```
<?php use App\Repositories;

use App\User;

class UserRepository {

    public function updateOrCreate($userData)
     {
        return User::firstOrCreate([
            'username' => $userData->username,
            'email'    => $userData->email,
            'avatar'   => $userData->avatar

        ]);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of your file `/app/UserRepositories/UserRepository.php`, you will need to namespace it using:

```
namespace App\UserRepositories;
```

Then you can import it to be used anywhere by:

```
use App\UserRepositories\UserRepository;
```